# Difference between SSE-KMS and SSE-C

Tags: amazon-s3

Can someone please explain the use-case for SSE-KMS vs SSE-C for encrypting the content of S3 bucket. To the best of my understanding I may use either technique in case I own an encryption key with which I wish to encrypt the content (as KMS allows to import external key). Which of the two I should use ?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 9):

That's correct. The main difference between SSE-KMS and SSE-C is who manages the encryption key.

#### SSE-C

If you want to manage the encryption key yourself, you need to include that encryption key as part of every request to S3. **If you lose the encryption key, you lose all the objects that are encrypted by this key.**

#### SSE-KMS

If you store it in KMS, you don't need to include it in the requests to S3. Instead, just upload/download your files normally and KMS will talk to S3 and handle that for you.